# Radio button to select one box only....ERROR

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

Something is wrong with the following code cause I can select more than one radiobutton at the same time.... How can I make the following code select only one radiobutton? Please help.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_BGlist">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:RadioButton ID="Radio1" GroupName="BG_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="BG_fileNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7960/How-to-group-RadioButtons or http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/radiobutton-inside-gridview-how-to-get-it-work-as-normal

Comment: What about using a `RadioButtonList` control like it is in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_radiobuttonlist) demo?

Comment: @Ghurkas Thanks ... But can I nest a RadioButtonList in a ListView as it is in my case? and how? I haven't been able to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>The easiest way to accomplish this is to just wrap your listview in an ASP.NET Panel or GroupBox, and ASP will implement the grouping you want.</del>

Adding a panel doesn't group radio buttons together if they are contained in some sort of repeater.  Probably the best solution is to use a RadioButtonList as suggested in [Grebets' Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24891295/361762).

If that doesn't suit your needs you can use javascript to alter the radio buttons after they have been created.  The following code will work when added to the bottom of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var inputName in inputElements) {
        var input = inputElements[inputName];
        if (input.type === "radio") {
            input.name = "Group1";
        }
    }
</script>
```

The script can be simplified if you are using jQuery.

Comment: Red the Panel documentation but it didn't help....I also tried to add the Panel in the ListView LayoutTemplate and it didn't work either....

Comment: You're absolutely right the Panel doesn't work.  It does in a normal case but it looks like the ListView/repeaters break that functionality.  Editing answer...

Comment: The javascript works well as long as the RadioButton AutoPostBack is set to False.

Comment: Well I was quick to think that the javascript above worked well....In fact it helps to select one single radio button in case of RadioButtons nested in a ListView, however it affected my code behind. RadioButton radioBtn = (RadioButton)itemRow.FindControl("Radio1"); stopped working and I can't find Radio1 in code behind anymore.

Comment: Yeah it's a pretty bad hack--sorry it doesn't work in your case.  The only way to group a Radio Button in HTML is by assigning the name attribute--which will break ASP.NET on the server side.  You could try rendering the Radio Button as a straight HTML and find another way to read the data server-side, or do as others have suggested and use a RadioButtonList instead--which is probably the better solution.

Comment: I fixed the problem....The solution can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910933/the-value-of-the-selected-radio-button-is-empty-after-adding-a-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think the most effective way will be use RadioButtonList:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" DataTextField="BG_fileName" DataValueField="BG_fileName" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_BGlist">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And if you preffer to use datasources in codebehind (like I do):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string BG_fileName { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string bgFileName)
    {
        BG_fileName = bgFileName;
    }
}

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        RadioButtonList1.DataSource = new List<MyClass>
        {
            new MyClass("test string 1"),
            new MyClass("test string 2"),
            new MyClass("test string 3")
        };
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```