# The value of the selected radio button is empty after adding a jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview

This is my last attempt to solve the problem of my Radio button scenario. I can't figure out how to select one button only. (By the way I can't use RadioButtonList cause it doesn't allow html codes inside its block so it doesn't suit me).

I have a list of pictures and radio buttons that are selected in a ListView as follows:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_BGlist">
        <ItemTemplate>                
            <input id="Radio1" name="BG_list" type="radio" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>'/>
            <img alt="" style="width:150px" src="/Images/Editors/BG/<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>">                  
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

Unfortunately the ListView mechanism assigns a different name to each radio button behind the scene which means that I can select multiple radio buttons. I want to be able to select one button only.
So I added the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var inputName in inputElements) {
        var input = inputElements[inputName];
        if (input.type === "radio") {
            input.name = "BG_list";
        }
    }
```

Now I can select one single button BUT it created another problem in codebehind. The value of the selected button is always empty. Why? Can anyone see the error?

CODE BEHIND

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.ListView1.Items)
                {
                    //RadioButton radioBtn = (RadioButton)itemRow.FindControl("Radio1");
                    var radioBtn = (HtmlInputRadioButton)itemRow.FindControl("Radio1");

                    if (radioBtn.Checked)
                    {
                       // Do Stuff
                        //Response.Write(radioBtn.Value);                       
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery where deselect all `radio` button except the clicked one, see below jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    // bind change event for radio button
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        // remove checked attribute for all radio button except the current one.
        $('input[type=radio]').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/17/)**